# Jquery - How to get location name details by latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a stable solution or Jquery plugin to get location name details by passing latitude and longitude.

I know there was a way using Google Reverse Location API but looking for ready made solutions.
Not sure is there any free version plugin available for this.

Answer (score 0):

Head to www.geocod.io and obtain a free API key; they provide unlimited reverse geocoding with no rate limits; you can make an Ajax call and pass the lng and lat values to return the info I believe you’re looking for. They have straight forward documentation on implementation;

Sample call:
https://api.geocod.io/v1.3/reverse?q=38.9002898,-76.9990361&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY"

Comment: thnks. heads to geocod.io but they support for US and Canadian address nd was looking for global.